# jQuery how to replace root node with a different element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace the root node of a group with a different element, but `replaceWith` doesn't seem to work.

```
div = $('<div></div>'); 
div.replaceWith('<span></span>');  // returns [<span></span>]
console.log(div);  // [<div></div>]

div = $('<div><span></span></div>');
div.replaceWith('<a></a>');  // returns [<div><span></span></div>]
console.log(div);  // [<div><span></span></div>]
```

The div doesn't get replaced, and the returned value is always itself and not the replaced node (the div). This seems backwards from the normal (documented) implementation where the replaced element is returned.

```
div = $('<div><span></span></div>');
div.find('span').replaceWith('<a></a>');  // returns [<span></span>]
console.log(div);  // [<div><a></a></div>]
```

So how can I replace the root node with another element if `replaceWith` doesn't work?

Comment: typo? `div.replaceWith('<span></span');` missing `>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach is to create a replacement element first, then append the contents of the original element into it. Like this:

```
var orig = $('<div>dasdasd<span>dasdas</span>dasdeasd</div>');
var repl = $('<span></span>');
repl.append(orig.contents());
```

---

As for the behavior of `replaceWith` you've described, that's actually intentional. Quoting the [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

> Prior to jQuery 1.9, `.replaceWith()` would attempt to add or change nodes in the current jQuery set if the first node in the set was not connected to a document, and in those cases return a new jQuery set rather than the original set. The method might or might not have returned a new result depending on the number or connectedness of its arguments!
>
> As of jQuery 1.9, `.after()`, `.before()`, and `.replaceWith()` always
>   return the original unmodified set. **Attempting to use these methods on
>   a node without a parent has no effect** — that is, neither the set nor the
>   nodes it contains are changed.

---

Comment: So how can I replace the node without a parent with a new element while keeping all it's children?

Comment: One possible approach is to collect its contents, then wrap it with another element (a replacement).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because it doesn't know which part of the `<div><span></span></div>` structure you want to replace. You may need to do

```
div.find('div').replaceWith('<a></a>');
```

Comment: `div.find('div')` returns an empty array because `find` only works on children.